# How to INF mod: Replacing 32bit dlls with 64bits

Tags: windows, drivers, inf

I've got a driver setup for 32 bit: An INF file and an x86 folder with two 32 bit dlls. I need to replace these 32 bit dll files with 64 bit ones. I just simply overwrite 32 bit files but no lock.

How can I make 64 bit version of the driver?

**Update:**

I tried original setup files on 32 bit Windows XP, setup asks for WdfCoinstaller01009.dll, I just simply browse & point the file from somewhere on XP.

```
;-------------- WDF Coinstaller installation

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstaller_CopyFiles = 11

[silabser.Dev.NT.CoInstallers]
AddReg=CoInstaller_AddReg
CopyFiles=CoInstaller_CopyFiles

[CoInstaller_CopyFiles]
WdfCoinstaller01009.dll

[SourceDisksFiles]
WdfCoinstaller01009.dll=1

[CoInstaller_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000, "WdfCoinstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[silabser.Dev.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService = silabser, silabser_wdfsect
[silabser_wdfsect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = 1.9
```

Comment: Please provide more information.  For example there is likely a generic driver for that device offered by Microsoft, have you tried that driver, instead of trying to hack a driver that likely will cause system crashes?

Comment: Windows XP 32-bit drivers cannot be used on a 64-bit installation of Windows Vista and/or Windows 7.  Please provide information about the device your trying to use.

Comment: You must provide a 64-bit Windows installation with a 64-bit driver dll.  The inf simply tells what driver Windows should be using.  So unless you have a 64-bit driver everything you try won't work.  The driver does not have to be signed, you can disabled the security measure, but it MUST be 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace 32 bit files with 64 bits. It works. My 32 bit setup files required an extra dll—`WdfCoinstaller01009.dll`—I just added the missing file now it works.

It's better to add separate 64 bit folder - x64:

```
[SourceDisksNames.x86]
1=%Disk_Description%,"silabser.sys",,\x86

[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1=%Disk_Description%,"silabser.sys",,\x64
```

What was my story:
I needed to use a custom design card -from Windows XP 32 bit- on Windows 7 64 bit but I had no device driver. I've used Driver Backup utility and created the device driver installation files. However that pack contains 32 bit dlls. I found 64 bit version of these public dlls and modified the INF.

Comment: Did the drive add any registry entries? Both the file-system and the registry have 32-bit and 64-bit specific locations, and putting stuff just any-old-place may not work correctly. Did you thoroughly test to make sure it works 100% and not just *seems* to work?

Comment: Luckily no registry conflicts.